# Add a new column with count depending on occurence within a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframse such as

```
Groups SP   Letters
G1     SP1  A
G1     SP1  Z
G1     SP1  A
G1     SP2  X
G1     SP3  X
G1     SP4  B
G2     SP2  A
G2     SP5  B
G2     SP3  X
G2     SP23 A
```

and I would like to add a column (`Nb_column`) which would be the count of unique `SP` value within each `Groups` but where `Letters` are in a list `the_list=['A','B']`

here I should then get:

```
Groups SP   Letters Nb_column
G1     SP1  A       2
G1     SP1  Z       2
G1     SP1  A       2
G1     SP2  X       2
G1     SP3  X       2
G1     SP4  B       2
G2     SP2  A       3
G2     SP5  B       3
G2     SP3  X       3
G2     SP23 A       3
```

Where

- there are **2** `SP` (**SP1,SP4**) with a `Letters` in `the_list` for the G1.
  And
- there are **3** `SP`  (**SP2,SP5** and **SP23**) with a `Letters` in `the_list` for the G2.

Does someone have an idea in pandas please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isin` to check for the existence, then `groupby().nunique()` and map back:

```
nb = df[df['Letters'].isin(lst)].groupby('Groups')['SP'].nunique()

df['Nb_column'] = df['Groups'].map(nb)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html)+[`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)+[`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) on a masked version of SP (by default the NaNs are not counted by `nunique`):

```py
df['Nb_columns'] = (df['SP'].where(df['Letters'].isin(the_list))
                     .groupby(df['Groups']).transform('nunique')
                    )
```

output:

```
  Groups    SP Letters  Nb_columns
0     G1   SP1       A           2
1     G1   SP1       Z           2
2     G1   SP1       A           2
3     G1   SP2       X           2
4     G1   SP3       X           2
5     G1   SP4       B           2
6     G2   SP2       A           3
7     G2   SP5       B           3
8     G2   SP3       X           3
9     G2  SP23       A           3
```

Answer (score 4):

We can select from the `SP` column based on where `Letters` [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) `the_list` using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) then use [`groupby nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) to get the corresponding number of unique values per group. Then [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the DataFrame to make the new column aligned with `Groups`:

```
df = df.join(
    df.loc[df['Letters'].isin(the_list), 'SP']
        .groupby(df['Groups']).nunique()
        .rename('Nb_column'),
    on='Groups'
)
```

Alternatively to [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) we can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to scale and create the new column from that:

```
df['Nb_column'] = (
    df.loc[df['Letters'].isin(the_list), 'SP']
        .groupby(df['Groups']).transform('nunique')
        .reindex(index=df.index, method='ffill')
)
```

`df`:

```
  Groups    SP Letters  Nb_column
0     G1   SP1       A          2
1     G1   SP1       Z          2
2     G1   SP1       A          2
3     G1   SP2       X          2
4     G1   SP3       X          2
5     G1   SP4       B          2
6     G2   SP2       A          3
7     G2   SP5       B          3
8     G2   SP3       X          3
9     G2  SP23       A          3
```